# Isn't time to start asking in Arabic?

Tags: discussion

A lot of us speak /Read Arabic well. .. so why don't we start asking and answering in Arabic ,, we're really losing a lot of time trying to translate the a answers we write , plus .. no meter how we translate it won't be clear as when you write it in Arabic , please don't make me vote down , even if you didn't like it  , because nothing will change , this is my point of view , and when u vote it down , nothing will change ;P

Comment: This issue was also brought up back in the commitment phase on Area 51.  The old discussion can be read here: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/islam-would-foreign-language-questions-be-permissible

Comment: It isn't a waste of time, if we are doing it for Allah than we have all the time in the world, plus the reward in this life and the next Insha'Allah.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest problem with having a *bilingual* site is that, as the site would be community-moderated, the community *at large* would need to be bilingual for it to truly work.  Otherwise, if half the questions are written in a language that only half the community can understand, only half the community can actually contribute (or, if necessary, moderate) which just decreases the overall efficiency.

This site, back in the commitment phase, was built under the premise of being held in English; the original discussion on whether or not foreign-language questions would be accepted can be read here:

- https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5209/41603

While it may seem a good method to expand the community, by opening it to foreign-language questions what would more likely happen is to have two distinct communities living on the same site, each doing their own thing, each with only half the available resources (i.e. community) at their disposal.

This runs counter to the general Stack Exchange model, that tries to focus Q&A topics for a single expert community.

The [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) site-proposal process is open to all; while our current site is built around the idea of an Islamic Q&A site for an English audience, there is nothing stopping anyone from proposing a new site, still using this same Stack Exchange system, for Arabic users (or Hindi, or Urdu, or Farsi, or even a multilingual site).  The major criteria is that enough people are interested in the idea to form a viable community.

Remember, however, that even though foreign-language sites are welcome on the Stack Exchange network, Stack Exchange itself is still an American company (and thus predominantly English-speaking).  If you do wish to propose a non-English site on Area 51, you should also read the following discussions:

- https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2598/41603
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53004/132874

Comment: A good additional point is that: even if the content were entirely in Arabic, all of the menu/guidance/user interface text would still be in English. A half-baked localization is  worse overall, in my opinion.